# Where can I find mailfromd RPM's for CentOS 6?

Tags: centos, rpm, gnu, altlinux

I have been trying to locate an RPM for GNU Mailfromd and it's dependencies and have been quite surprised to find it absolutely nowhere on the 'net.  Only place I could find any [RPM's were for ALTLinux](http://packages.altlinux.org/en/Sisyphus/srpms/mailfromd/get).

Anyone know where I could find it?  I have some advanced filtering needs for postfix and it seems to be the most flexible solution available.

I've had a lot of trouble trying to compile the dependencies (also not available it seems) myself (GNU mail-tools, guile, etc).

Does GNU have an RPM repository somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are currently no mailfromd RPMs for EL6. You will need to create them yourself or find someone to do it for you.